# BeagleBoard: setting ALSA master volume

Tags: beagleboard, alsa

I'm trying to set the master volume with alsa on a BeagleBoard (with Ubuntu installed) but when is executed the following code the result is always: "Mixer simple element not found"

```
elem = snd_mixer_find_selem(handle_mix, sid);
if(elem==NULL)
{
printf("Mixer simple element not found\n");
}
```

I've runned the same code on a computer (samsung NC10) and the result is correct and I can set the master volume. Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixer elements are hardware dependent, and even on the same hardware, mixer element IDs can change in different driver versions.

Run `amixer scontrols` to see which mixer controls are actually available.